# difference of left join and left outer join

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, t-sql, join

In SQL Server join syntax we can use `LEFT JOIN` or `LEFT OUTER JOIN` and query result with each of above join not difference. this is a question for me that which are more useful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no difference, they are absolutely 100% identical in function - the `OUTER` keyword is optional in the syntax. Personally I prefer `LEFT OUTER JOIN` as it's a bit more explicit.

You can see more details here:

[MSDN : Using Outer Joins](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx)

and here:

[MSDN : FROM (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177634%28v=sql.100%29.aspx)

The relevant bit in the latter document:

```
LEFT [ OUTER ]
```

> Specifies that all rows from the left table not meeting the join
>   condition are included in the result set, and output columns from the
>   other table are set to NULL in addition to all rows returned by the
>   inner join

The same description applies whether you use the `OUTER` keyword or not.